# escape quotes inside quotes in TSQL string

Tags: t-sql, string, quotes

I'm trying to run the following TSQL statement on Microsoft SQL 2008

```
DECLARE @tmpMessage nvarchar(max)

SET @tmpMessage = 'select * from openquery(GLive,''select ID from Links WHERE [HREF] LIKE ''test'''')';

exec sp_executesql @tmpMessage
```

the above code doesnt work because the single quotes before **test** closes the main quotes around the second select statement **select ID from Links ....**

and yes i have to put my statement in a string first before executes it because **openquery** function wont allow me to do somethin like

```
select * from openquery(GLive,'select ID from Links WHERE [Href] LIKE ''' + @Var + ''''')
```

any suggesstions would be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a template that I use whenever I'm dealing with variables in an openquery statement to a linked server:

```
DECLARE @UniqueId int
, @sql varchar(500)
, @linkedserver varchar(30)
, @statement varchar(600)

SET @UniqueId = 2

SET @linkedserver = 'LINKSERV'
SET @sql = 'SELECT DummyFunction(''''' + CAST(@UniqueId AS VARCHAR(10))+ ''''') FROM DUAL'
SET @statement = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(' + @linkedserver + ', ' 
SET @Statement = @Statement + '''' +  @SQL + ''')'
EXEC(@Statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also try out the [QUOTENAME](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,26614,26714,26736,26751&sugexp=ldymls&tok=vM4dJOHqTJilpmad1c3JQA&xhr=t&q=sql+quotename&cp=7&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=sql+quo&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=4e781b66e30e329a) command.

Comment: it kinda worked for me after removing the '[' and ']' the quotename function added, thanks